# Find a line orthogonal to a chord of a circle

Tags: geometry

There is a circle with center $O$. $AB$ is a chord of the circle. $K$ is a point on $AB$ such that $AK=10$ and $KB=16$. $CD$ is the diameter passing 
through $K$, $CK < KD$.

Moreover, $OK=6$.

Please help me find $OL$ ($L$ is a point on $AB$ and $OL$ is orthogonal to $AB$).

Here are my attempts.

Radius $r = 14$ and $CK=8$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the point L?

Comment: L is a point on AB.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Compute the length $KL$. Then, Πυθαγόρας is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$OK=OC-CK=14-8=6$$
$$AL=\frac{AB}{2}=13$$
$$KL=AL-AK=3$$
$$OL=\sqrt{OK^2-KL^2}=3\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 0):

If $r=14$ and $CK=8$

$AL=BL=\frac{AB}{2}=\frac{10+16}{2}=13$

Hence $KL=AL-AK=13-10=3$ and $OK=r-CK=14-8=6$

And as the points, $O,L,K$ form an right angled triangle, with OK as hypotenuse, $$3^2+OL^2=6^2 \Rightarrow OL=3\sqrt{3} $$